# Creating the Hello, World automator action in OSX Lion yields "launch path not accessible"

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion, automator

I had a few automator actions developed under OSX 10.6, which successfully executed under automator without an issue. The binary products of these actions continues to work under OSX 10.7 (Lion), but compiling them from source fails.

In trying to debug this issue, I created the dirt simple "Hello, World" action, but it will not successfully execute in automator, both the ObjC and Applescript variant getting "launch path not accessible", no matter where in the workflow they are placed.

The development path I have followed is:

1. In XCode 4.1 (build 4B110, from the App Store), create a new project, and select Automator Action" as the type
2. Set Output type to com.apple.cocoa.string
3. Under the ObjC variant, change the runWithInput:error method to return @"Hello, World!" Under the AppleScript variant, change the runWithInput_fromAction_error_ method to return "Hello, World!"
4. Compile the action via the run arrow
5. Open the new action in finder via right click on the action under the Products group
6. Double click on the action and let automator install it
7. In automator, create a single item workflow (but have tried multi-item workflows) with the new action
8. Execute the workflow via the run arrow and receive the "launch path not accessible" error

I have tried restarting xcode, restarting automator, removing my ~/Library/Automator directory after shutting down automator, and combinations of the above without change. At this point, however, I'm out of ideas.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So I believe that I was triggering a bug in XCode 4.1 for Lion (didn't test on snow leopard) that was creating an invalid build of the automator actions. Following this script under XCode 4.2 beta for Lion (Build 4D139) generates automator actions that work as expected.

I'm not deleting the question in the hope that someone else will stumble upon it via google, though perhaps someone can close it.

Comment: Why not answer and accept your solution (update Xcode) - that way it will be here and even if it gets closed as localized, there is a solution to the problem you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment recommendation, and for posterity, the issue appears to be localized to XCode 4.1. XCode 4.2 betas do not exhibit this behavior and appear to operate as expected following the workflow I outlined in the question.

Comment: I also ran into this and found that the **Principal class** key in the Info.plist was not getting set correctly (it should be the name of your script).

Comment: actually this is not the whole problem. Tried that with 4.1 and no luck. Seems 4.2 has some big changes with Automator or something like that. Needed even after the update it didn't run on the first try. Have double checked the values, cleared the build folder etc. Suddenly it worked and I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

after stopped searching for it, found an tutorial but can't test it anymore because I already upgraded to Xcode 4.2. It would be nice if someone could verify that:
http://macosxautomation.com/automator/xcodefix/index.html